# Python: how to create multiple threads running at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, coroutine

I am creating a game using Python and tkinter, and when I tried to add some music, the function making the music stopped the rest of the script (and also the window).
So I need to create a new thread I think to play the audio and keep the window working...

I tried some things making errors, not running, or stopping the window, I currently have :

```
window.after(2000,showText,"Text 1")
window.after(2000,playSound,"Sound 1.wav")
window.after(7000,showText,"Text 2")
```

*Important detail : the playSound function returns nothing, so nothing needs to wait for it.*
*I also don't know much about programming in Python, I prefer using LUAU.*

Answer (score -1):

Try using the module `threading`. I found [this article](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) very useful for understanding the core concepts and setting up my first multithreaded program

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens : `window.after(2000,threading.Thread(target=playSound,args="Sound 1.wav").start)` .